# nesting of el expressions in JSF for resource API

Tags: jsf, el

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:primefaces-ui/#{car.manufacturer}.jpg']}"/>
```

I would like to calculate the inner el first and then calculate the path using resource API.
I tried `<c:set>` tag but its variable is also an EL, so it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `+=` operator to String-concatenate EL variables, if you really can't use `library/name` for some reason.

```xml
<p:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:primefaces-ui/' += car.manufacturer += '.jpg']}"/>
```

This operator was introduced in EL 3.0 (Java EE 6, December 2009). In older versions, you cannot nest EL expressions nor String-concatenate EL variables that way. You need to use [`<c:set>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/c/set.html) to prepare the dynamic key before using it in another EL expression by simply inlining the EL expression in a string:

```xml
<c:set var="resourceName" value="images:primefaces-ui/#{car.manufacturer}.jpg" />
<p:graphicImage value="#{resource[resourceName]}"/>
```

An alternative is simply using `library` and `name` attributes instead of generating an URL based on those via `#{resource}` mapping:

```xml
<p:graphicImage library="images" name="primefaces-ui/#{car.manufacturer}.jpg" />
```